# cannot get api/auth/logowanie problem node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

When I  try to get data from my db I get an information "Cannot GET /api/auth/logowanie". I'm using node.js and mongodb. I've tried to solve it but nothing worked. (the port and url is in 100% correct)

My auth.js file

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const CryptoJs = require('crypto-js');
const User = require('../models/user');
//REJESTRACJA
router.post('/rejestracja', async (req, res)=>{
    const newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: CryptoJs.AES.encrypt(req.body.password, process.env.PASS_SEC).toString(),
        

    });
    try{
        const saveduser = await newUser.save();
        res.status(201).json(saveduser);
    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }

});

//LOGOWANIE
router.post('/logowanie', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username});
        !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong username or password")
        const hashedpassword = CryptoJs.AES.decrypt(user.password, process.env.PASS_SEC);
        const password = hashedpassword.toString(CryptoJs.enc.Utf8);
        password !== req.body.password &&
            res.status(401).json("Wrong username or password")
        res.status(200).json(user);
    }catch(err){ res.status(500).json(err); }

})
module.exports = router
```

My index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const userRoute = require("./routes/user");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");


const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { CLIENT_RENEG_LIMIT } = require('tls');
const { application } = require('express');
mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to Mongoose server'))
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/users', userRoute);
app.use('/api/auth', authRoute);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5300, ()=>{
    console.log('Listening on port 5300');
});
```

[And screenshot from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of1Eb.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint in the auth.js file is a POST request. And you are sending a GET request from Postman.